# Making X axis be in the exact order and exact value in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I'm trying to make a graph in excel where the x-axis is the values of 1/r^2 (The r being the distance in the first column) and the y-axis being the force calculated by Colomb's law (the third column). Unfortunately with the way how 1/r^2 has calculated, as the distance increases the result decreases, resulting in the first result being 100 then slowly going down to 1. I need a way to make it so that the x-axis of the chart has the exact values and also in the exact order on the scatter chart I am making, but every time I insert the chart it always puts it in the opposite way(going from 1 to 100). I also need it to be the exact values as well (100, 25, 11.111, etc) but I'm don't know how I'm suppose to go about this

[Image of the columns, first is there for calculation purposes, 2nd is  x, 3rd is y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gykNM.png)

Comment: To make the x-axis go from low to high, you can sort the data with distance descending. Are you saying that you want to have the data labels on the chart axes instead of at the tick-marks?

Comment: Yes if it is possible

Comment: That's pretty unusual tbh. If you don't mind my asking, why do you want to do that?

Comment: It's a bit of stupid reason. Honestly speaking, its mostly just to see if I can and to see how it looks like if I do if that makes any sense.

Comment: TBH I'm not sure you can even do this, but if we did figure it out, several of your data points (near to x=0) are very close together - the axis labels would be very crowded.

Comment: Ah, I see. a bit of a shame, but it's fine. I appreciate the help you gave me since I didn't know you could sort the data by distance descending so thank you.

Comment: When you are dealing with this type of data, make sure you are using an XY scatter plot.  Sorting the points will only make a difference in how the line gets  connected, the data points are where they are.  If you want to get more resolution on your points that are closer to the origin, you could change the format of both axis to LOG 10.  The data points near the origin look much more spread out, and the 100 point not so far away.  By keeping it log vs log, you also maintain the nice straight line visual for the slope of your line.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't hard to do. You add another data series along the axis and add data labels with the desired text. This is not a good data set to demonstrate this, however, since most of the points are clustered so closely together at small X values.

But here's what to do. Add a column of zeros next to the 1/r² column. The first chart below shows the original data with blue circles. The second has added the new data as orange crosses. In the third chart I've added data labels below the orange points, using the X values instead of the default Y values. Finally I've applied some formatting, making the orange crosses the same color as the axis, to mimic tickmarks, and hiding the original X axis labels.

[image: Custom X Axis Labels]

I've written a few tutorials that exploit this approach over the years:
[Custom Axis Labels and Gridlines in an Excel Chart](https://peltiertech.com/custom-axis-labels-and-gridlines-in-excel-chart/)
[Reciprocal Chart Axis Scale](https://peltiertech.com/reciprocal-chart-axis-scale/)
[Simulated Probability Chart Example](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ProbabilityChart.html)
[Creating Exponential Notation Axis Labels](https://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/ScientificNotation.html)